# opening the WebPage on clicking the TabHost

Tags: android, html, android-tabhost

I have created the TabHost in my application and I have four tabs in it. I have already created four different classes for the four tabs of the TabHost. All the four tabs are supposed to show the different views when you select( or Click) them.

In one of the Tab(Tab number 4) named "Info" of TabHost, I just want to open the WebPage that displays the Information of the application I am developing.

I have the URL for that webpage but I don't know how should I open that WebPage by clicking or selecting the forth Tab.

If anyone knows it, please tell me.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 0):

You must include a WebView component http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html within your Tab

Regards!